# How to broadcast hard key events as system broadcast in android?

Tags: android, system, broadcast

Can I create a new system broadcast in android? For example, an action with hard keys that fires a broadcast?

I want to perform an action when a particular combination of hard keys of android device is pressed being on the home page of device (i.e. no particular application need to be running).

Any suggestions and answers are most welcome!

Comment: Are you making your own custom Android ROM?

Comment: No no, I only want my application to respond to my generated broadcast as if a system broadcast is received. I want that when a key combination is pressed my app shoud receive a broadcst and respond to it as any application responds to system broadcast, in the same manner as any application responds to POWER_CONNECTED broadcast( when allowed to. )

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can do it, have key listener and listein for key event when your logic passes then just send broadcast sendBroadcast(new Intent("MY_KEY_PRESSED")); ;)

Comment: Can u help me in defining this broadcast, the one you metioned as MY_KEY_PRESSED?? I want to listen to the broadcast without launching my app, and launch my app on receiving this broadcast.